# When using Laravel migrations how do I chose the database?

Tags: laravel, migration

How do I chose the database that I'd like to do the migration? 'users' is the table. How do I select the database that I'd like to use?

This is what I have:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up() {
            Schema::create('users', function($table) {
                $table->increments('id');

                $table->text('email', 50);
                $table->text('username', 20);
                $table->text('password', 60);
                $table->text('password_temp', 60);
                $table->text('code', 60);

                $table->integer('active');
                $table->text('remember_token', 100)->nullable();

                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down() {
            Schema::drop('users');
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I'll leave it here for others.

```
Schema::connection('mysql_users')->create('users', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->text('email', 50);
    $table->text('username', 20);
    $table->text('password', 60);
    $table->text('password_temp', 60);
    $table->text('code', 60);

    $table->integer('active');
    $table->text('remember_token', 100)->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The migrate command uses the databases specified in your `app/config/database.php` file. I'd imagine the easiest way to use another database is to create a new file in a new folder, e.g. `app/config/mynewenv/database.php`, change the appropriate database variables in there, and run `php artisan migrate --env=mynewenv`.

Comment: Would it be ok to do something like Config::set('database.default', 'mysql_users'); before Schema::create?

Comment: It would be a bad practice, because it ties the migration to a hardcoded database, but I'm sure you could get it to work by setting a configuration at runtime, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The database is configured in `app/config/database.php`.